# Definitions of ordinal addition and multiplication

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, ordinals

For any two sets $\alpha$ and $\beta$, let $\alpha+\beta = \{\alpha', \alpha+\beta'\}$ and $\alpha\cdot\beta = {\alpha\cdot\beta'+\alpha'}$, where $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ are variables taking as values all elements of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively.  These operatons are well-defined by induction for all well-founded sets.  Then the following statements all have "one-line" inductive proofs (for all sets $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$):

- $\alpha+0=0+\alpha=\alpha$
- $\alpha\cdot 0=0\cdot\alpha=0$
- $\alpha\cdot 1=1\cdot\alpha=\alpha$
- $\alpha+(\beta+\gamma)=(\alpha+\beta)+\gamma$
- $\alpha\cdot(\beta+\gamma) = \alpha\cdot\beta + \alpha\cdot\gamma$
- $\alpha\cdot\beta\gamma=\alpha\beta\cdot\gamma,$

where $0 = \varnothing$ and $1 = \{0\}$.  In each case the induction hypothesis is that the identity holds whenever we replace one of $\alpha$, $\beta$, or $\gamma$ by $\alpha'$, $\beta'$, or $\gamma'$ (note that this is vacuously true when the set being replaced is empty).  For example, the proof that addition is associative is as follows:

$$ \alpha+(\beta+\gamma) = \{\alpha'+(\beta+\gamma), \alpha+(\beta+\gamma)' \} = \\ \{\alpha'+(\beta+\gamma), \alpha+(\beta'+\gamma), \alpha+(\beta+\gamma') \} = \\ \{(\alpha'+\beta)+\gamma, (\alpha+\beta')+\gamma, (\alpha+\beta)+\gamma' \} = \\ \{(\alpha+\beta)'+\gamma, (\alpha+\beta)+\gamma' \} = (\alpha+\beta)+\gamma.$$

It's also possible to prove that the sum or product of two ordinals is always an ordinal, and in fact $+$ and $\cdot$, when restricted to ordinals, are equivalent to the usual definition of the ordinal sum and product.  Yet I've never seen ordinal arithmetic defined in this way!  So my question is, is this definition well-known?  And if so, why is it so seldom used?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "$\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ are variables taking as values all elements of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively."?

Comment: I mean, for example, $\alpha+\beta = \{\alpha' : \alpha\in\alpha\} \cup \{\alpha+\beta' : \beta' \in \beta\}$. The notation is from John Conway's *On Number's and Games*, specifically the chapter on $\mathbf{On_2}$. In that chapter, Conway implicitly uses the definitions of ordinal addition and multiplication I described here to prove that certain "nim" sums and products are equal to certain ordinal sums and products, although he never states the definitions explicitly.